# Small PHP MVC framework with namespaces

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm looking for a very small MVC framework, or just sample architecture, that makes use of namespaces. I'm a bit curious on how to do it and would like to see a small example of that. Thanks! Any tips or links?

Comment: http://matrix.include-once.org/framework/feature - click on "coding.names" - So Frostbite and Breeze might be interesting to you.

Answer (score 3):

This is a one page mvc framework [Fat-Free](http://fatfree.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Shaneprrlt/AtomicPHP

You can watch the development step by step on youtube:

[Part 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kLrmIr0obYk)
[Part 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9pFSPO1gazE)
[Part 3](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=opMQeko86Ms)

And it sure would help to take a look at the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php).

Comment: All three of the youtube links are dead.